# How to call Javascript function inside WTForms radio element?

Tags: javascript, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm new to wtforms and flask. I'm trying to do so that when that a user changes the radio buttons, the text would change. However, currently the onchange does not work, nor does onclick and when I remove it, the text appears but does not change at all when the buttons are changed and remains the same.

```
    {{ wtf.form_field(form.doc, class="form-control", onchange="myFunction()") }}


    </div>
   <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  
  function myFunction(){
         
         if (document.getElementById('doc-0').checked) {
              value = document.getElementById('doc-0').value;
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + value;
          }


       else if ( document.getElementById('doc-1').checked) {
              rate_value = document.getElementById('doc-1').value;
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + value;

        }
        else if (document.getElementById('doc-2').checked) {
              rate_value = document.getElementById('doc-2').value;
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected:" + value;

        }

        else {
   
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: NOTHING" ;
        }
     }


        </script>
```

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong and what I should do. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.
A `wtforms.RadioField` consists of several input fields. An event listener must be registered manually for each of these input fields. I recommend a separate script block for this.

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      {{ wtf.form_errors(form, hiddens="only") }}

      {{ form.doc.label }}
      {{ wtf.form_field(form.doc) }}
    </form>
    <output id="result">You selected nothing.</output>
  </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
{{super()}}
<script type="text/javascript">
  (() => {
    // Select all input fields by name and iterate over them.
    const elems = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="doc"]');
    elems.forEach(elem => {
      // Register an event listener for the change event.
      elem.addEventListener('change', evt => {
        // Update the text as soon as there is a change.
        const value = evt.target.value;
        const label = evt.target.parentElement.textContent.trim();
        const output = document.getElementById('result');
        output.innerHTML = `You selected ${label} (${value}).`;
      });
    });
  })();
</script>
{% endblock %}
```